# Finding the row id number of a specific field

Tags: php

The organization that I work for has a voting platform that was built before my tenure and I cannot find the specific index needed to get the voting conditions needed to trigger (limiting votes to one per person). I was told that a print_r would give me the appropriate data needed but I am not a php developer by any means and can't quite figure out how to even run the print_r. Code below:

```
if ($thewebform->data[6][0] == $row->id) //this is the row that needs to be 
edited

echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
href="/sites/default/files/awardsvoting/awardsvoting.css"/>';
echo '<hr/>';
echo "<strong>form name</strong><br/>";


// get the webform module
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'webform') 
."/includes/webform.submissions.inc");

// get all the webform submissions with the nid of the webform
$filters = array('nid' => 6548);

try {
$thewebforms = webform_get_submissions($filters);
// print_r($thewebforms);

//determine how many votes the project is entitled to, based on membership 
type
// if it's a corporate membership, they get two votes
if ($row->membership_type == '6'){
$votesallowed = 2;  
}
// if it's a non-profit membership, they get two votes
else if ($row->membership_type == '3'){
$votesallowed = 2;  
}

// if it's a student membership, they get none
else if ($row->membership_type == '5') {
$votesallowed = 0;  
}

// if it's any other type of membership, they get one
else {
$votesallowed = 1;
}
//echo "votes allowed = " . $votesallowed;
// figure out how many votes the project has already cast, if any
// the index of $thewebform->data has to be readjusted for the index of the 
org_id in the webform
$votesused = array();
    foreach($thewebforms as $thewebform) {
    // echo $thewebform->data[6][0];
    // print_r($row->id);
    if ($thewebform->data[6][0] == $row->id) {
        $votesused[] = $thewebform;
        }
    }

// determine if the project has any votes left  
$votesremaining = $votesallowed - count($votesused);
//echo "remaining votes: " . $votesremaining;
echo "Votes remaining: " . $votesremaining . "/" . $votesallowed . "<br/>";

if ($votesremaining > 0) {
    echo '<a class="myButton" href="voting url' . $row->id . '&cid=' . 
$_SESSION[CiviCRM][userID] . '">Vote! 
</a>';
}
echo '<hr/>';
}
catch (exception $e) {
drupal_set_message($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: "how to even run the print_r".... `print_r($thewebforms);` (or whatever variable it is you're wanting to look at). http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php . That'll show you the data structure of that object / array on screen when your script finishes executing. We don't know this data structure, or the context in which this code is executing, or the sample data being used to create this scenario, so right now that's as much help as anyone can realistically give you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `print_r` for the row ID already in the code on line 10. You can uncomment this by deleting the `//`. This will show you all the data inside $row->id, which is likely just a number. I don't know what the rest of your code or your database looks like, so this may or may not actually give you what you want.

There is more information about `print_r` [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Doing a `print_r` like this is part of what's called debugging. Be sure to do your debugging only on a development server and not in the live environment. Otherwise, anyone using the voting system might be able to see the debugging information.

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments below, you can also try using [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) instead of `print_r` by replacing

```
print_r($row->id);
```

with

```
echo $row->id;
```

Comment: I have added the rest of the voting code to my question. I have tried uncommenting both print_r and I still can't get it to show me the code.

Comment: Try echo the print_r in order to see the var print

Comment: In your question you mention limiting voting to one vote per person. In the code it mentions votes per project. Is it safe to assume that the two terms are interchangeable in this case?

Comment: @Worthwelle yes, those are interchangeable. In this case depending on your membership level you are entitled to a different number of votes. What I'm looking for is the id # for the org_id field which is what is tied to the membership type

Comment: You may need to view the page source in your browser to see what was printed. If that doesn't show the value, can you verify that the changes you made were uploaded to the server you're running the code on?

Comment: The view page source did not show me what was printed. The changes that I've been making have been uploaded as any other change that I have made to the code has showed up.